# Points where the gravitational field of N masses vanishes

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

Given a configuration $C$ of $N$ distinct fixed points of equal mass in the plane (eventually, in space), let $f_C(N)$ denote the number of points $P$ for which the gravitational field at $P$ vanishes.

For example $f_C(2)=1$ for all $C$ consisting of two points, and for a $C$ consisting of $3$ collinear points, $f_C(3)=3$.

I conjecture that $f_C(N)$ is always finite and nonzero.

Is this true?

Comment: This function is not well defined, it depends on how the particles are distributed.

Comment: @s.harp: no, it only vanishes at the midpoint.

Comment: @YvesDaoust right, didn't think clearly at all.

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282770/conjecture-finitely-many-points-where-gravitational-field-due-to-n-masses-vanis).

Comment: And [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361162/number-of-points-where-gravitational-field-due-to-n-point-masses-vanishes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been simultaneously crossposted to both MO.SE & P.SE.